# Trying to use bootstrap and noscript to create an alert

Tags: javascript, noscript

I'm trying to create an alert for if JavaScript is disable in the user's browser.  I figured the best way to do this would be to just use a bootstrap dismissible alert like this:

```
 <noscript>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                aria-hidden="true">
            &times;
        </button>
        Warning! JavaScript is disabled.  This site may not work properly without it.
    </div>
</noscript>
```

When I run the code though it just prints out everything inside of the noscript tags as if it were text.  How do I correct this?  Or is there another way to check if they're using JavaScript or not?

Comment: Doesn't bootstrap's alert need JavaScript?

Comment: No, the css will make it work fine. Try refreshing the page a couple times. This happens when you first disable javascript.

Comment: Refreshing it about 5 times worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap alerts work fine with just html and css so they will work in `<noscript>` tags.

This happens when you first switch javascript off. Just refresh the page a few times.